# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 6 elements

Tags: python, data-analysis

Hi I am trying to run an exercise from Howard B. Brandy's book "Quantitive Technical Analysis" I know he used python 2.x but I am using Python 3.9 therefor updating the code. The Code is listed below and the error I get I think when  Calling the function to retrieve historical intra-day data looks like a mismatch with the index but not sure how to resolve is. Could you please guide me what needs to be modify to have it runing in Python 3.9 This is the code I am using:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests

def getGoogleIntradayData(ticker,numSeconds,numDays):

    #  Define some variables     
    parsedData = []
    syncChar = 'a'
    numSkipLines = 7

    # Form the url
    urlStr = 'http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q='
    urlStr += ticker
    urlStr += '&i=' + str(numSeconds)
    urlStr += '&p=' + str(numDays) + 'd'
    urlStr += '&f=d,o,h,l,c,v'
    # Open the url
    resp = requests.get(urlStr)
    rawData = resp.text
    lines = rawData.split('\n')
    nrows = len(lines)
    
    for i in range(numSkipLines,nrows):
        #  check for empty line at end of data
        if (lines[i]==""): continue
        dtField, o, h, l, c, v = lines[i].split(',')
        if dtField[0]==syncChar:
            #  Full datetime
            dtBase = dtField[1:]
            dtIncr = 0
        else:
            #  Datetime increment
            dtIncr = int(dtField)
        dtValue = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp\
                    (float(dtBase) + (dtIncr*numSeconds))
        o, h, l, c = [float(x) for x in [o, h, l, c]]
        parsedData.append((dtValue, o, h, l, c, v))
        
    qt = pd.DataFrame(parsedData)
    qt.columns = ['datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    qt.index = qt.datetime
    del qt['datetime']
    return qt    
qtIntra = getGoogleIntradayData('AAPL',300,5)

print(type(qtIntra))
print(qtIntra.head())
print(qtIntra.tail())
```

I am getting the following error :

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Could you please guide me what needs to be modify to have it runing in Python 3.9

Comment: Your reference is (very) out of date. `http://www.google.com/finance/getprices` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Very good I am trying to update this code to run it with current data. Any sugestions?